# Representing all possible values or a subset of values

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

I have a class that needs to return a set of values e.g

```
public abstract class AbstractRule {

   public abstract String getName();
   //Property is an example here.
   public abstract Set<Property> getApplicability();
}

public class ConstrainedRule extends AbstractRule {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "ConstrainedRule";
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Property> getApplicability() {
    return ImmutableSet.of(propertyA,propertyB);
  }
}

public class GlobalRule extends AbstractRule {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "GlobalRule";
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Property> getApplicability() {
    // This Rule is applicable on all properties.
    return ImmutableSet.of(propertyA, propertyB, ...);
  }
}
```

Here I wish to define a Rule which is applicable on all Properties,which would have been easy if I knew the universe of properties that exist, which I don't.

What would be a good way to represent such an Applicability ?

One option would be to model the Set of Property as a class say:

```
class PropertyApplicability {

   public static final PropertyApplicability ALL = new PropertyApplicability(true, ImmutableSet.of());

   private final Set<Property> applicables;
   private final boolean applicableToAll;

   private Applicability(boolean applicableToAll, Set<Property> applicables) {
       Preconditions.checkNotNull(applicables);
       this.applicables = ImmutableSet.copyOf(applicables);
       this.applicableToAll = applicableToAll;
}

   //Only way to create applicability with a set of properties
   public Applicability(Set<Property> applicables) {
     Preconditions.checkArgument(applicables.size() > 0);
     this(false, applicables);      
   }

   //Getters
}
```

But I wondered if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: What parts of the Set<> interface are users of your rules using? If all they will do query Set::contains then you can implement a UniversalSet with `bool contains(T item) { return true; }`

Comment: Expanding on @Caleth's comment, are you sure you need a ``Set<>`? If all you need is `contains()` then your own, simpler interface will do better, possible with a wrapper-aroind-Set implementation